# Handshaking lemma

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, applications

I'm collecting mathematical facts that can be easily explained to non-mathematicians and that have both "unimportant" and very important applications. For example, Theorema Egregium can be applied to eating pizza and is very important in creating maps.
Handshaking lemma has an obvious "application" to counting handshakes at a party. It is also very useful in proofs and in general graph theory. I can't think of a concrete important example though, easy to explain within a short time.
Any ideas about handshaking lemma or similar examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Are you asking about general examples of such mathematical facts, or about specific use cases for the handshaking lemma?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify. Actually, both - handshaking lemma would be great, but any other examples very useful as well.

Comment: I think this is actually a soft question since it is opinion based. I suggest you add the tag "soft question".

Comment: By other examples do you mean something like the fair cake cutting problem? Relevant to fairly cutting cakes as well as dividing more "important" resources.

Comment: @Χpẘ, yes, for example. I actually haven't thought about this one, thank you!